# How to get total number of pages in oracle with scrollableresults

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, oracle10g

I am trying to get the number of rows for a given query (in order to paginate some ui page).

I am using hibernate jpa on a oracle db. My code is

```
TypedQuery<AClass> query = getQuery();
Query hquery = query.unwrap(Query.class);
ScrollableResults resultsCount = hquery.scroll();
resultsCount.last();

int rowCount = resultsCount.getRowNumber() + 1;         
resultsCount.close();
```

This always return a value of 1 although there are many more rows.
I must be doing a newbie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like

```
Query<Long> countQuery = getCurrentSession().createQuery("select count(*) from rows");
return countQuery.uniqueResult().intValue();
```

Comment: If possible I would like to use the same query to count and to retrieve the actual data.

Comment: but in such case you won't benefit from the paging, as you'll fetch all the data to get the total count (instead of using count(*) by Oracle, and then single page at a time)